# Приостановить выполнение второго эффекта jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
...
    $(".side-bar").blur(function()
    {
        $("#links").slideUp(600);
        $(".categories").slideDown(600);
    });
...
```

Подскажите, как можно замедлить выполнение slideDown(600); на время пока не выполнится slideUp(600); В примере выше эффект получается таким, что #links сворачивается и тут же появляется .categories и следует (подымается вверх) за #links. Может можно как-то отследить выполнилось ли первое условие чтобы начать второе либо отложить выполнение slideDown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".side-bar").blur(function() {
    $("#links").slideUp(600, function() {
        //функция вызывается один раз после завершения выполнения анимации
        $(".categories").slideDown(600);
    });
});
```

документация по [slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".side-bar").blur(function() {
  $("#links").slideUp(600, function() {
    $(".categories").slideDown(600);
  });
});
```